Triac false triggering


Hi
I am using a triac to control loads from a microcontroller. In the Triac circuit shown both R1 and R9 are connected to microcontroller. The problem is, whenever AC power supply got turned on, the bulb connected to the T1 TRIAC flashes once. Kindly tell the reason for this if anyone are aware. Also suggest me the design parameters to be considered to avoid this.

Some questions to help get an answer: (a) Can you include the part of the schematic which contains the microcontroller? (b) What state does the microcontroller pin connected to TRIAC1_LIGHT default to at power up? (c) Could the microcontroller software produce a high on TRIAC1_LIGHT during initialisation?

This is a wholly unsuitable circuit for anyone but the most careful person because it's very dangerous. Please demonstrate that you understand the dangers.

What bulb? Incandescent? LED? Flashes ones immediately when voltage is applied or slightly after?

@Chester Gillon,  I removed all the connections from the microcontroller up to the optocoupler but the problem still persists.

@Winny, we tried both incandescent and 0 watts LED bulbs, both will blink once immediately after voltage is applied.
